# Automatically delete custom close reason comments on migration

Tags: feature-request, comments, migration, custom-close-reasons

When you vote to close a question as a duplicate, a comment is automatically posted ("possible duplicate of [Post]"). If the question is eventually closed as a duplicate, the comment is (now) automatically deleted.

When you suggest a site in a comment and the post is migrated to that site, the comment is deleted.

When you vote to close with a custom reason, a comment is automatically posted with the reason ("This question appears to be off-topic because it is about unicorns"). When others add votes to that reason, they automatically upvote the auto-comment. But when the post is migrated, the comment stays with it even though it's even more obsolete than the two other types of automatically deleted comments.

[Example that prompted this](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/5310/what-did-lady-joanna-ask-of-dream?noredirect=1). The last comment "try the question in scifi.stackexchange.com...." was not migrated, but the other two were (now deleted destination-side)

When a post is migrated, any automatic custom-close-reason comments should be removed from the post, like "belongs on [site]" comments are.

Comment: How often have you seen this happen?

Comment: What if the custom close reason comments aren't saying, "belongs on site X" but rather describing some other problem with the question?  That might be relevant to the question even after migration.

Comment: @AaronBertrand I've only noticed it the once, or I'd probably have made this FR before.

Comment: @Servy If there is a problem that caused the question to be closed that is still relevant on the destination, the question shouldn't have been migrated in the first place, until the problem was resolved.

Comment: @Kevin Agreed, it shouldn't have been.  That doesn't mean it doesn't happen sometimes anyway.

Answer (score 2):

[The example you cite](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/5310/what-did-lady-joanna-ask-of-dream?noredirect=1) is actually a very strong reason to *not* implement the automatic deletion you're talking about: it includes other helpful suggestions for improving the post, which are still relevant on the destination site. Of course, @Kevin is right, those should have been addressed before the migration was allowed...

Personally, I think it is ok to delete canned auto-comments upon migration (or closure as a duplicate, or what have you), but as soon as you allow a user to enter custom text, then you can't possibly know that every future custom close reason should be automatically deleted upon migration. The suggestion in one of the comments cited in this very question is a very good example of something that a user entered (and could have entered into a custom off-topic close reason comment) that is *still* relevant on the destination site. We need to be very careful about automatically purging user-entered content, especially in a case this obscure (you've only seen it once, so is it worth developer time and effort until it becomes a much more widespread problem, when a flag can already deal with it?).

Comment: The comment that was actually deleted had some useful advice, but the only comment I'm talking about deleting automatically is "This question appears to be off-topic because it is about a media which is not considered anime or manga."  That is entirely irrelevant on scifi, where we do accept non-anime-or-manga questions (in fact, most are).

Comment: @Kevin but what if that comment included more information (such as the one I identified)? People could enter 10 different reasons into a single custom off-topic comment, and how could you suggest that all of them will be obsolete / invalid after migration?

Comment: As I said to Servy above, if a close reason is still relevant on the destination, the question shouldn't have been migrated. The asker will still be able to see the comment on the source site.

Comment: @Kevin But those issues can't always be addressed before migration (since a post can be migrated to many sites without moderator intervention), and for what possible reason would the OP go back and see the comment on the source site? They'd have to intentionally go back to find it, and I'm not sure why they would. And if the issue still remains, it just means someone else is going to have to add yet another comment on the new version of the post, start the Vote to Close process over again, etc.

Comment: I'd think even if he didn't see the comment before migration, he'd get a notification for it that would bring him to the old comment - and if he doesn't bother to acknowledge/read it on the source anyway, why would he on the destination?

Comment: @Kevin because not all users are on the site 24/7. I miss inbox notifications all the time.

Answer (score 1):

I'm in favour, because they can become contradictory, for instance on https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19312269/retrieves-fields-from-different-tables-in-visual-basic-2010.

[image]

Whilst this was obviously off-topic on Academia it's not on Stack Overflow.

It doesn't look good for an OP to come back to Stack Exchange, find their question on a different site with a comment saying that it's still off-topic.